# Using Sqlsrv for PHP 8.2

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I have successfully installed PHP 8.2 on Ubuntu 20.04. I am trying to add the SQLSRV extension following [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver16#installing-on-ubuntu) directions.

The installation for `SQLSRV` completes successfully.

However, when I try to run a function in PHP using `SQLSRV` extension, I get the error:

> "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried:
> /usr/lib/php/20220829/sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/sqlsrv.so:
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"

As the error reports, the /usr/lib/php/20220829/ directory does not contain the sqlsrv.so file. Instead the SQLSRV installation places the sqlsrv.so file to the /usr/lib/php/20210902/ directory.

Both the sqlsrv.so and pdo_sqlsrv.so files are automatically installed to the '20210902' directory.

I have tried moving the sqlsrv files to the '20220829' directory, but then I receive an error that I am trying to load two different versions of PHP, '20210902' and '20210902'.

Any help to get these extensions working properly would be great!

Listed above are the steps I tried.

Answer (score 3):

It has been released at the end of January as a beta for now.
You can find it here:

https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases

Answer (score 2):

Official release 5.11 from Microsoft is out now, compliant with PHP 8.2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

As of Jan 1st 2023, according to [Microsofts Main PHP developers](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1420) , PHP8.2 is not yet supported.