# SQLSRV Not Showing in PHP INFO using PHP 8.2.1 and Sql Server 2019

Tags: php, iis

I have download and install `SQLSRV32.EXE` and `SQLSRV40.EXE`

I have configured `php.ini` by adding extension

```
extension_dir = "ext"

[PHP_SQLSRV]
extension = php_sqlsrv_81_ts.dll
extension = php_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64.dll
```

My Windows server 2019 and IIS restart several times after new configured php.ini,

I use am using SQL Server 2019, and my PHP version is as follows:

```
PHP 8.2.1 (cli) (built: Jan 3 2023 23:36:33) (NTS Visual C++ 2019 x64), 
Copyright (c) The PHP Group Zend Engine v4.2.1, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies,
```

But `SQLSRV` Not Showing in `PHP INFO`

Is there something wrong ?

Comment: I think you need One or the Other of these 2 dll's. `php_sqlsrv_81_ts` for a 32bit Apache/PHP and `php_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64` for a 64 bit Apache/PHP

Comment: Did you also download and install the ODBC Drivers as well

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-the-sql-server-driver-for-php

Comment: Not completely sure, but it looks like there is no driver yet for PHP 8.2

Comment: Those PHP 8.1 bits are not designed for PHP 8.2.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, how to do download and install the ODBC Drivers?

Comment: Did you read the link I gave you + All the links on that page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Sqlsrv for PHP 8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75076460/using-sqlsrv-for-php-8-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the official GitHub from the Microsoft team (https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql), there will be a release with PHP 8.2 support in January 2023.

**UPDATE:**
Microsoft Drivers 5.11 for PHP for SQL Official Release:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server